# angularjs form validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have test in two case,but in seven case, it doesn't work.
my angularjs version is 1.6.2

following is my code of form html.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal createForm" role="form" id="validateForm" novalidate ng-init="isEmpty = false;" name="userCreateForm">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label labelSame">姓名 :</label>
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           name="createName"
           ng-model="createName"
           placeholder="请输入用户姓名"
           ng-pattern="regularList.uniqueName"
           required
           ng-blur="userCreateForm.createName.$blured = false;errorShow()"
           ng-focus="userCreateForm.createName.$blured = true; endErr='';"
           autocomplete="off"/>
    <span style="color:#F36856;display:inline-block;width:350px;position: absolute; top: 7px;left:450px;" ng-if="userCreateForm.createName.$blured == false && userNameErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{userNameErr}}</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label labelSame">部门 : </label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           ng-model="createDepart"
           name="createDepart"
           placeholder="请输入部门"
           required
           ng-pattern="regularList.depart"
           ng-blur="userCreateForm.createDepart.$blured = false;errorShow()"
           ng-focus="userCreateForm.createDepart.$blured = true; endErr='';"/>
        <span class="error" ng-if="userCreateForm.createDepart.$blured == false && departErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{departErr}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label labelSame">角色 : </label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select ng-model="firstRole" class="form-control selectForm" ng-init="role = '操作员'">
            <option ng-repeat="role in roleList" value="{{role.id + ':' + role.code}}">{{role.roleName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label labelThree">用户名 : </label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               name="createUser"
               ng-model="createUser"
               required
               placeholder="请输入6-32字符的英文或数字"
               ng-pattern="regularList.pwd"
               ng-blur="userCreateForm.createUser.$blured = false; errorShow()"
               ng-focus="userCreateForm.createUser.$blured = true; endErr='';"/>
        <span class="error"  ng-if="userCreateForm.createUser.$blured == false && userErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{userErr}}</span>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label labelForth">初始密码 : </label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               name="createPassword"
               ng-model="createPassword"
               required
               ng-pattern="regularList.password"
               placeholder="必须包含6-32字符的大小写英文或数字组合不包含特殊字符"
               ng-blur="userCreateForm.createPassword.$blured = false;errorShow()"
               ng-focus="userCreateForm.createPassword.$blured = true; endErr='';"/>
        <span class="error" ng-if="userCreateForm.createPassword.$blured == false && passwordErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{passwordErr}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label labelSame">手机 : </label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               name="createPhone"
               ng-model="createPhone"
               required
               placeholder="请输入11位数字的手机号码"
               ng-pattern="regularList.telphone"
               ng-blur="userCreateForm.createPhone.$blured = false;errorShow()"
               ng-focus="userCreateForm.createPhone.$blured = true; endErr='';"/>
        <span class="error" ng-if="userCreateForm.createPhone.$blured == false && phoneErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{phoneErr}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label labelSame">邮箱 : </label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               name="createEmail"
               ng-model="createEmail"
               placeholder="请输入有效的邮箱"
               required
               ng-pattern="regularList.email"
               ng-blur="userCreateForm.createEmail.$blured = false;errorShow()"
               ng-focus="userCreateForm.createEmail.$blured = true; endErr='';"/>
        <span class="error" ng-if="userCreateForm.createEmail.$blured == false && emailErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{emailErr}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
<label class="control-label labelSame">省份 : </label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           name="createProvince"
           ng-model="createProvince"
           disabled/>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label labelForth">描述信息 : </label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <textarea class="form-control formTextarea"
              ng-model="createDescription"
              placeholder="选填"
              ng-pattern="regularList.inputContext"
              ng-blur="userCreateForm.createDescription.$blured = false;errorShow()"
              ng-focus="userCreateForm.createDescription.$blured = true; endErr='';"></textarea>
    <span class="wordStyle"><span class="wordSCount">{{createDescription.length ? createDescription.length : 0}}</span>/64</span>
    <span class="error" ng-if="userCreateForm.createDescription.$blured == false && descriptErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{descriptErr}}</span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

following is javascript code to validate input correct.

```
$scope.errorShow = function() {
  if ($scope.userCreateForm.createName.$error.required) {
    $scope.userNameErr = "姓名不能为空";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createName.$error.pattern) {
    $scope.userNameErr = "请输入正确的姓名";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createDepart.$error.required) {
    $scope.departErr = "部门不能为空";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createDepart.$error.pattern) {
    $scope.departErr = "请输入正确的部门";
  }else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createUser.$error.required) {
    $scope.userErr = "用户名不能为空";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createUser.$error.pattern) {
    $scope.userErr = "请输入正确的用户名";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createPassword.$error.required) {
    $scope.passwordErr = "初始密码不能为空";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createPassword.$error.pattern) {
    $scope.passwordErr = "请输入正确的密码";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createPhone.$error.required) {
    $scope.phoneErr = "手机号不能为空";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createPhone.$error.pattern) {
    $scope.phoneErr = "请输入正确的手机号";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createEmail.$error.required) {
    $scope.emailErr = "邮箱不能为空";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createEmail.$error.pattern) {
    $scope.emailErr = "请输入正确的邮箱";
  } else if ($scope.userCreateForm.createDescription.$error.pattern) {
    $scope.descriptErr = "长度不能超过64位";
  } else {
    $scope.userNameErr = "";
    $scope.departErr = "";
    $scope.userErr = "";
    $scope.passwordErr = "";
    $scope.phoneErr = "";
    $scope.emailErr = "";
    $scope.descriptErr = "";
  }
};
```

following is regular code

```
$rootScope.regularList = {
    telphone: /^1[34578]\d{9}$/,
    email: /^[a-z0-9A-Z]+([-|_|\.]+[a-z0-9A-Z]+)*@([a-z0-9A-Z]+[-|\.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/,
    password: /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}/,
    code: /^[0-9]{4}$/,
    uniqueName: /^[a-zA-Z|\u4E00-\u9FFF]{4,32}$/,
    depart: /^[a-zA-Z0-9|\u4E00-\u9FFF]{4,32}$/,
    pwd: /^((?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*[a-zA-Z])).{4,32}$/,
    pic: /^[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}$/,
    inputContext:/^.{1,64}$/
};
```

but function of errorShow doesn't work.
hope you can give me some advice.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change it And Use Like this Only Once If Work Then Go Ahed

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control"
                           name="createPhone"
                           ng-model="createPhone"
                           required
                           placeholder="请输入11位数字的手机号码"
                           ng-pattern="regularList.telphone"
                           ng-blur="userCreateForm.createPhone.$blured = false || errorShow()"
                           ng-focus="userCreateForm.createPhone.$blured = true; endErr='';"/>
        <span class="error" ng-show="userCreateForm.createPhone.$blured == false && phoneErr"><img src="../app/assets/image/error.png"/>{{phoneErr}}</span>
```